# MultiValueDictKeyError at /addbook/

Tags: python, mysql, django

```
def addbook(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        book_name =request.POST['book_name']
    Book = Book.objects.get()
        Book.save()
        return render_to_response('book_detail.html', {'books': books},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return render_to_response('addbook.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def book_detail(request):
    return render(request, 'book_detail.html')
```

the above is my view.py i am getting this error"MultiValueDictKeyError at /addbook/"

please help me

Answer (score 1):

That error means that 'book_name' isn't in your POST data.

If you want to handle that case, you can use book_name = request.POST.get('book_name'), which will default book_name to None if it isn't in the POST data.

If not, you need to make sure the form has an input called 'book_name'.